# How much, in taxes, does a typical American taxpayer pay toward public libraries?

Tags: united-states, taxes, local-government, funding, public-funding

I'm looking for an average or estimation of how much money public libraries cost a typical American taxpayer.

Comment: Libraries are funded at the local level, so the answer is going to be different for every city or county in the country.

Comment: @divibisan - Nonetheless, _an average or estimation_ of cost per typical American taxpayer, suggests to ignore such differences. The current figure should be about [$40.00 per capita](https://www.amacad.org/humanities-indicators/public-life/public-library-revenue-expenditures-and-funding-sources). The problems with answering are: older data; estimating the number of taxpayers, when different funding sources are used; and that the American Library Association web site is undergoing maintenance.

Comment: @RickSmith Particularly with regard to money, there is also the problem that the mean is often not very representative of 'typical' (you, me and Jeff Bezos probably have a mean net worth of $50 billion ), hence the use of alternative measures such as mode or median.

Comment: Another problem is that many "taxpayers" are not individual people, they're business and so on.  Might be easier to figure a per capita number: for the county I live in, it was $23.46 last year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm looking for an average or estimation of how much money public libraries cost a typical American taxpayer.

That figure is not directly available. However, available data may be used to derive an estimate.

For 2017, per capita taxation amounts to about $39.35. Using the number of housing units as a surrogate for "taxpayer," the average is about $93.67.

Housing units was selected as the surrogate because there is not a lot of difference among the various measures of "taxpayer" that may be chosen; local governments, in the US, often use property or real estate taxes on housing units for funding; and, where other types of taxes may be collected, ultimately, it is the residents of those housing units that pay those other taxes.

---

**Notes**

[Public Libraries Survey Fiscal Year 2017](https://www.imls.gov/sites/default/files/fy2017_pls_tables.pdf#page=36), published June 2019, Table 8. Total per capita operating revenue of public libraries, by source of revenue and state: Fiscal year 2017

- Total $42.34
- Federal $0.15
- State $2.82
- Local $36.37
- Other $2.99 -- This includes monetary gifts and donations received in the current year, interest, library fines, fees for library services, or grants.

Removing the "Other" category leaves $39.35 per capita.

---

[United States Population](https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/us-population/) 2017: 325,084,756

[Number of housing units in the United States ...](https://www.statista.com/statistics/240267/number-of-housing-units-in-the-united-states/) 2017: 136.57 million

[Number of households in the U.S. ...](https://www.statista.com/statistics/183635/number-of-households-in-the-us/) 2017: 126.22 million

[Summary of the Latest Federal Income Tax Data](https://taxfoundation.org/summary-of-the-latest-federal-income-tax-data-2020-update/): In 2017, 143.3 million taxpayers ....